# How can I overwrite the "next" slot in a QWizard?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm using a QWizard class, which contains several QWizardPage. For some pages, I need to do something when the "Next" button is clicked.

I tried to overwrite the `next` slot in my QWizard class; however, it seems this doesn't work. The program still went into the original `next` slot in the parent QWizard class instead of the one I implemented.

Is this because this `next` slot is virtual protected? How can I do some things after the next button is clicked?

---

The header file of my QWizard class follows.  By the way, the `accept` signal works fine as what I expected.

```
#ifndef PRIMERWIZARD_H
#define PRIMERWIZARD_H

#include <QWizard>

namespace Ui {
    class PrimerWizard;
}

class PrimerWizard : public QWizard {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PrimerWizard(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~PrimerWizard();
protected slots:
    void next();
    void accept();

protected:
    void changeEvent(QEvent *e);

private:
    Ui::PrimerWizard *ui;
};

#endif // PRIMERWIZARD_H
```

I create a new wizard instance via QtCreator's wizard (Ha XD)

The code is as follows:

```
PrimerWizard* pW = new PrimerWizard(this);
pW->exec();
```

And the signal-slot connection of `next` is created by QtCreator, I cannot find where it's actually connected. I think the connection is built in ui_PrimerWizard.h by this function:

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(PrimerWizard);
```

Comment: I have a similar situation. In my case I have wizard pages steps 1-6, and at step 4 I want to make a http request, wait for callback then move onto step 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `next` slot cannot be overwritten. However, the `validatePage` function for QWizardPage can. This function will be called when the "Next" or "Finish" button is clicked.